# A specific part of my JavaScript script doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am coding with Js, Vue JS, JQuery and firebase services.
There is one part of my code where all instructions i put are ignored, even a simple alert().
I have found the same problem earlier bute i resolved it by changing the position of the block that doesn't work.

````
    userMaker(getCookieValue('uid'), docPatient.data().nom); alert(utilisateur.nom);
 
//The code from here...
    console.log('Voici ca', todayRdvListId)
    for(var i = 0; i<todayRdvListId.length; i++){
        alert('hello')
        console.log('Le ForEach')
        db.collection('rdv').doc(todayRdvListId[i]).get().then((rdvDoc)=>{
            todayRdvList.push(rdvDoc);
            console.log("j'ai mis", todayRdvListId)
        })
    }
    
    document.cookie = 'uid='+utilisateur.uid+';nom='+utilisateur.nom;

//To here doesn't work

    var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                utilisateur: utilisateur,
                rdvAujour: todayRdvList,
            },
        })
        $(".nav-item a").on("click", function(){
            $(".nav-item a").removeClass("active");
            var select = $(this);
            select.addClass("active");
            $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
            var id = select.attr("data-bs-target");
            $(id).attr("class", "tab-pane fade show active")
        })```
````

Comment: If everything else is working you might want to add more of your code in your question.

Comment: Does anything improve if you put semicolons at the line ends?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows (untested):

```
const promises = [];
for(var i = 0; i < todayRdvListId.length; i++){
    promises.push(db.collection('rdv').doc(todayRdvListId[i]).get());
}
Promise.all(promises)
.then(rdvDocs => {    // rdvDocs is an Array of DocumentSnapshots
    todayRdvList.push(...rdvDocs);
});
```

or by using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);

```
Promise.all(todayRdvListId.map(rdvId => db.collection('rdv').doc(rdvId).get()))
.then(rdvDocs => {    // rdvDocs is an Array of DocumentSnapshots
    todayRdvList.push(...rdvDocs);
});
```

Comment: Hey @GuyRogerThéa, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed answer?